# Setting environment varilable for daemon / root process

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have a daemon process running on a server that needs access to an environment variable that specifies file path information (e.g. MYPATH=/a/b/c). I know how to specify this in my .bashrc file to give me access while I'm on the interactive shell, but unclear how to make sure a value accessible to a daemon process that's running as root.

In short, my question is: How do I set an environment variable that can be accessible by a daemon process running as root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a script - like

```
#!/bin/sh

export MY_VAR="some value"

exec /path/to/daemon
```

Put it in /etc/rc.X to use this script.

See the manual page for that (and read [what does the numbers mean in /etc/rcX.d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310350/what-does-the-numbers-mean-in-etc-rcx-d))

Comment: Curious, if I call export MY_VAR, is that variable then available to existing running processes?

Comment: No - just to the current environment and any process that inherits (runs) from it

Comment: You can use this method to sanitise the environment as well